# Visual Studio '15 Web Deploy continuously failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to a shared hosting account (SmarterASP). It was working perfectly fine but recently it mysteriously stopped working for no reason. I tried contacting support, spent 2 days talking to them and they say "it's working fine for us, something's wrong at your end". I'm not sure whether it's my end. The task always fails with this:

```
3>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to *url removed* ...
3>C:\Program Files     (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4295,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((12-Nov-16 3:07:55 PM) An error  occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
3>
3>(12-Nov-16 3:07:55 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on  the remote computer.
3>The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
3>Publish failed to deploy.
```

Nothing else at all. No further error messages. Is there any I could get a detailed error message what EXACTLY is causing the process to fail? I'm already considering to move to a VPS if the issue persists.

Comment: They were continuously saying they can deploy without any issues and "something is wrong at my side". I was sick of all this. Thats why, I bought a VPS and hosted the database on Azure. Problem solved. Everything works like a charm.

Comment: Great to hear that. I believe you dont need to purchase VPS, shared hosting is enough, it is cheaper. :) :) Good luck for you.